# half or quarter black screen in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android activity that when I launch sometimes (about 1 in 4 times) it only draws quarter or half the screen before showing it. When I change the orientation or press a button the screen draws properly.

I'm just using TextViews, Buttons, Fonts - no drawing or anything like that.

All of my code for initialising is in the onCreate(). In this method I'm loading a text file, of about 40 lines long, and also getting a shared preference. Could this cause a delay so that it can't draw the intent?

Thanks in advance if anyone has seen anything similar.

**EDIT** - I tried commenting out the loading of the word list, but it didn't fix the problem.

**EDIT 2** - I didn't manage to resolve the problem, but managed to improve it by adding a timer right at the end of the onCreate. I set a low refresh rate and in the tick changed the text of one of the controls. This then seemed to redraw the screen and get rid of the black portions of the screen.

Here is the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_abstract_background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeScore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ScoreLabel"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="SCORE:"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ScoreText"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ScoreLabel"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GameTimerText"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:minWidth="25dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GameTimerLabel"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/GameTimerText"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="TIMER:"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeHighScore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeScore" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HighScoreLabel"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="HIGH SCORE:"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HighScoreText"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/HighScoreLabel"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeHighScore"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMissing"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/yellow_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MissingWordText"
                style="@style/yellowShadowText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="MSSNG WRD"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/yellow_text" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/aVowelButton"
                    android:layout_width="66dp"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_vowel_button"
                    android:text="@string/a"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_text"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/eVowelButton"
                    android:layout_width="66dp"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_vowel_button"
                    android:text="@string/e"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_text"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/iVowelButton"
                    android:layout_width="66dp"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_vowel_buttoni"
                    android:text="@string/i"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_text"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/oVowelButton"
                    android:layout_width="66dp"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_vowel_button"
                    android:text="@string/o"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_text"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/uVowelButton"
                    android:layout_width="66dp"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_vowel_button"
                    android:text="@string/u"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_text"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TimeToStartText"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            style="@style/yellowShadowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button_menu"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="START!"
            android:textSize="28dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the OnCreate() and a few methods:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    isNewWord = true; 
    m_gameScore = 0; 
    m_category = getCategoryFromExtras();           
    //   loadWordList(m_category); 
    initialiseTextViewField(); 
    loadHighScoreAndDifficulty(); 
    setFonts();
    setButtons(); 


    setStartButton(); 

    enableDisableButtons(false); 


}

private void loadHighScoreAndDifficulty() {
    //setting preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(m_category, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int score = prefs.getInt(m_category, 0); //0 is the default value
    m_highScore = score; 
    m_highScoreText.setText(String.valueOf(m_highScore)); 

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(DIFFICULTY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    m_difficulty = prefs.getString(DIFFICULTY, NRML_DIFFICULTY); 

}

private void initialiseTextViewField() {
    m_startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    m_missingWordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MissingWordText); 
    m_gameScoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreText); 
    m_gameScoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreLabel); 
    m_gameTimerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GameTimerText); 
    m_gameTimerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GameTimerLabel); 
    m_timeToStartText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimeToStartText);
    m_highScoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HighScoreLabel); 
    m_highScoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HighScoreText);
}

private String getCategoryFromExtras() {
    String category = ""; 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        category = extras.getString("category");
    }
    return category;
}

private void enableDisableButtons(boolean enable) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aVowelButton);
    button.setEnabled(enable);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eVowelButton);
    button.setEnabled(enable);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iVowelButton);
    button.setEnabled(enable);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oVowelButton);
    button.setEnabled(enable);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uVowelButton);
    button.setEnabled(enable);
}

private void setStartButton() {
    m_startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            m_gameScore = 0; 
            updateScore(); 
            m_startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            m_timeToStartText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startPreTimer(); 
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: code? layout? examples? we can only guess without something to look at

Comment: As @Mutmatt said, better if you add code/layout.  Easy way to test if it's the text file, just comment out the file parsing part of your code and see if that makes it go away.  Loading a text file on the UI thread (which onCreate() is on) maybe not be your best option (even if it's not your primary issue), check into AsyncTask for handling that.

Comment: As Mutmatt said ... you should really be posting some code here

Comment: same problem any solutions?